# Saving sublime text snippets in a directory for reuse on different pc

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext3

Hey guys i am new to Sublime. I read in documentation how to create snippets. Now my question is how to save them in to a directory and then maybe reuse them on another PC.
Thanks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Save the file. When you do, you'll need to determine two things: its file name & where to save it.

File name: The file must end with .sublime-snippet, like this: foo.sublime-snippet. What goes in front of .sublime-snippet is up to you. I like to use the tabTrigger if at all possible, along with the main part of the scope in front of the tabTrigger, giving me this: html-p.sublime-snippet.

Where to save it: When you press Save, Sublime Text should automatically try to save the file in the right folder.

You shouldn't have to worry about the location, as Sublime Text should take care of it for you, but if for some weird reason you're not in the right place, then you'll need to navigate to the right location.

Answer (score 1):

You should save snippets in your `Packages/User` directory, where `Packages` is the directory opened by selecting `Preferences -> Browse Packages...`. You can then copy the `.sublime-snippet` files to your other PC by whatever means you prefer.